# Cordova-plugin-geofence onTransitionReceived() method not working

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm working with Ionic2 and Angular2 in my project. When I install cordova-plugin-geofence (https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence). Geofence is configured as follows:

> App.ts

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

  if (window.geofence === undefined) {
    console.log('Geofence Plugin not found');
  }else{
    console.log('Geofence plugin found');
    window.geofence.initialize();
    const geofence = this.geofenceService.create({
      longitude: -8.404015,
      latitude:  43.339147,
    });

  this.geofenceService.addOrUpdate(geofence).then(function () {
      console.log('Geofence successfully added');
  }, function (reason) {
      console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
      });
    }
  });
```

> HomePage.ts

```
window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function (geofences) {
  geofences.forEach(function (geo) {
    console.log('Geofence transition detected', geo);
  });
}
```

The service geofence.service.ts it was configured as tsubik's ionic2 geofence example: https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence/blob/master/app/services/geofence-service.ts

No errors appear on console in all geofence configuration process but method window.geofence.onTransitionReceived() not log anything when geofence transitions happen.

What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You have to define a radius and a transition type. Don't make the radius to close, take something like 1000 or 3000m.

Comment: @Samuel Fraga Mateos, Are you getting notification.? Even i am facing issue on this plugin.

Comment: @Joerg I have defined radius and transition type on a default geofence. When I create a new geofence I only override latitude and longitude parameters.

Comment: @Aish123 I'm not getting notifications at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Docs are incorrect, you need to subscribe:

```
Geofence.onTransitionReceived().subscribe( res =>{

          res.forEach(function(geo) {
            console.log(geo);
          });

        },
        (err) => console.log(err),
        ()    => console.log("done !")
    );
```

And if you want to use funtion "getWatched", you need to have swift support.. just add:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support --save

Config.xml

```
  <preference name="UseLegacySwiftLanguageVersion" value="true"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" spec="~1.6.2"/>
```

If you need an array of geofences currently being monitored:

```
   Geofence.getWatched().then((geofencesJson) => {

          const geofences = JSON.parse(geofencesJson);

      this.sendLog("wathced ");
      this.sendLog(geofencesJson);

          return geofences;
    });
```

These settings work for me.